# Refresh part of a html page (a popup)

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I have seen similar questions but no solution that works for me.

When I click a button in my html, a cookie is set, lets say cookie_zero.

Then, based on this cookie, cookie_zero, another cookie is read, cookie_one.

However, the page needs a refresh in order to get the updated cookie.

Is there a method to only refresh a section of a HTML page? It could be the code below "POPUP SETUP":

```
Lots of HTML . . .

<!-- POPUP SETUP -->

<div id="popup" class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2 id="popup-headline"></h2>

        <p id="question"><?php echo $_COOKIE['cookie_one']; ?></p>

        <p id="answer"><?php echo $_COOKIE['cookie_two']; ?></p>

        <p class="popup-small-button"><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#"><br>Close</a></p>

        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: "*However, the page needs a refresh in order to get the updated cookie.*" - care to elaborate on this issue? Is it the issue you have, and are working around, or does it actually have to refresh for some other reason.

Comment: Because its requested from the PHP, and the PHP section is not updated. Thats what i need it to do. I know i can send the variable with jQuery and update the <p>, but thats not solution im looking for, if, there is another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i can help! You just need to make use of an HTTP GET request. See method below.

This works...

```
<?php
// Test.php
setcookie("cookie_zero", 1);
?>

<!-- button -->
<button data-click="set_cookie">Set cookie</button>

<!-- html body for live  feed -->
<div data-feed-for="set_cookie">

</div>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>

let clickbtn = document.querySelector("*[data-click='set_cookie']");
let feedfor = document.querySelector("*[data-feed-for='set_cookie']");

let http = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new window.ActiveXObject("XMLHTTP.Microsoft") : new XMLHttpRequest();

let set_cookie = function(){
    http.open("GET", 'test2.php', true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
            // Response in json
            var response = JSON.parse(http.response);
            // Feed screen
            feedfor.innerHTML = response.cookie_one;
        }
    }
    http.send(null);

}

clickbtn.addEventListener("click", function(s){
    set_cookie();
});
```

Now create a php file that processes the cookies

```
<?php

// test2.php
setcookie("cookie_zero", mt_rand(10,500));

$cookies['cookie_one'] = $_COOKIE['cookie_zero'];

echo json_encode($cookies);

?>
```

Now run. It works fine
You should note that you cannot reload a particular section of an HTML document.

Cheers.

## Josesphi